# Passing String into an API method with a Route Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a method on an API Controller where I've set the route in an attribute, but I don't seem to be able to pass a string into this. When I try to hit this with an Ajax Request from the browser the console shows the following error:

> BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to
>   invalid syntax.

The string I'm passing over is huge, but unfortunately is the only way I can import the data into the legacy application I'm working with. The test URL I'm using is (brace yourselves):

`http://localhost:50915/api/job/import/ALMIG&sup3123456&sup32%20DAY%20ECONOMY&sup320170720&sup320170721&sup30&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup322&sup3Lara%20Croft%20Way&sup3Derby&sup3&sup3&sup3DE23%206GB&sup3Stuff&sup310&sup31&sup30&sup325&sup30&sup3&sup31%7CI%20Great%20Danger&sup30&sup30&sup30&sup3&sup3&sup30&sup3true&sup30&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup31&sup30&sup30&sup316&sup3Baden%20Road&sup3Stoke-on-Trent&sup3&sup3&sup3ST6%201SA&sup3&sup30&sup30&sup30&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup30&sup30&sup30&sup30&sup3&sup30&sup31&sup30&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3&sup3Liane&sup307730044916&sup3Lara&sup307730044916&sup30&sup3d2f0acf7-50e1-4a53-96ce-4fffd00b1a96&sup30`

And the method is defined as below, the code inside is irrelevant as I put a break point on the start of the method which is never hit:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/job/import")]
public int TmsImport([FromBody]string import)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Edit: Added Ajax Request

```
job.confirmBookings = function () {
    // TMS Import
    job.toConfirmRow.filter(function(obj) {
        var jobRow = obj;
        var strArray = [];
        for (var prop in jobRow) {
            if (jobRow.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                strArray.push(jobRow[prop]);
            }
        }
        var joinedStr = strArray.join(job.seperator);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: joinedStr,
            url: job.tmsString, 
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("TMS ID: " + data + " | " + status);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try "api/job/import/{import}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First format the route template correctly

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/job/import")] //Matches POST api/job/import
public int TmsImport([FromBody]string import) {
    // do something...
}
```

Also you should post the data in the body of the request. If the payload is large then you do not want that in the URL

Comment: String is passed over as null - it's not null before it enters the request, it looks like it's just not passed over for some reason - I'll modify my answer with the ajax request included

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it by changing `data: joinedStr` to `data: "="+joinedStr`